# Computation of two-sided probability density functions from their cumulants using Laplace transform

Tags: probability-distributions, laplace-transform

The computation of one-sided probability density functions (PDFs)
from their cumulants using Laplace transform is proposed by following paper:

M.N. Berberan-Santos, Journal of Mathematical Chemistry, Vol. 41, No. 1, January 2007 (© 2006)71-77.
[a link](http://web.ist.utl.pt/berberan/data/114.pdf)!

I need similar computation for two-sided PDF.

Comment: The link isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Expansion of the method for two-tailed PDF is developed in the following paper:

"Expressing a probability density function in terms of another PDF: A generalized Gram-Charlier expansion" 
M.N. Berberan-Santos, Journal of Mathematical Chemistry, Vol. 42, No. 3, October 2007 (© 2006)
[a link](http://web.ist.utl.pt/ist12219/data/115.pdf)!